# Error in console when working win Arrays in Angular. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular

I am trying to build a basic to do list app using js and html in Angular. I am trying to append my input to an array list, but I get the following error in the console only after clicking my Submit button  [image]. The code runs and compiles fine for now though.

todolist.component.html:

```html
To Do list
<div>
    <input id='listinput' type="text">
    <button id='submitbutton' (click)=addtolist();>Submit</button>
    <button id='clearbutton'>Clear list</button>
</div>

<ul id='itemlist'>list here</ul>
```

todolist.component.ts:

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


export interface ListInterface{
    todolistarray: {listitem: string, completed: boolean}[]
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todolist',
  templateUrl: './todolist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todolist.component.css']
})

export class TodolistComponent implements OnInit {

   mainlist: ListInterface = {} as ListInterface;

  addtolist(){
    
    var listitemvar = (document.getElementById('listinput') as HTMLInputElement).value;
    alert(listitemvar);
    (document.getElementById('itemlist') as HTMLDataListElement).innerText = listitemvar;
    this.mainlist.todolistarray.push({listitem: listitemvar, completed: false});
    }

    
  constructor() {  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Thank you in advance for any help or tips.

Comment: todolistarray is not initialized.

Comment: How and where do I initialize it properly?